# Privacy Implications of choosing a domestic versus international bridge

Tags: surveillance

For a user in the United States, what are privacy considerations in choosing a domestic bridge versus an international bridge? Is there any evidence if US versus non-US nodes have been found to be malicious more often in the past? Would openly connecting to an overseas bridge dramatically increase the chances of being caught up in mass surveillance as it raises raises red flags by overtly connecting overseas?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no such implicatioons at all. If the bridge is compromised or accessed without a key - it does not matter where it is.